# how to tell which key has the most value stored in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key, python-3.6

I have a whole program that has a previous dictionary in a different function that gives me a list of departure and arrival cities for planes.

I am trying to write a function that determines which keys have the most outgoing flights and I am unable to figure out how to find which keys have the most values. My dictionary is named flights which has the departure city as the keys and the arrivals as values.

def outgoing(flights):
    length = 0
    for i in (flights):
        if (len(flights[i]) > length):
            length = (len(flights[i]))
            break
        else:
           continue

```
for i in flights:
    if (len(flights[i]) == length):
        pop = (len(flights[i]))

print ("the most outgoing flight is: " , [i])
```

this code is suppose to work but for some reason it isn't giving me the correct max output from the file. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to just use the builtin max function and list comprehension:

```
def outgoing(flights):
    print(max([len(i) for i in flights]))
```

If you want to stick with your code, you need to compare to the max each iteration:

```
def outgoing(flights): 
    max_outgoing = 0 
    for i in flights:  
        if(max_outgoing < len(flights[i])):
            print(max_outgoing)
            max_outgoing = len(flights[i])
```

EDIT: On re-reading your question, it seems that you'd also like to get the key of the max value. The just do this:

```
def outgoing(flights): 
    max_outgoing = 0 
    max_key = None
    for i in flights:  
        if(max_outgoing < len(flights[i])):
            print(max_outgoing)
            max_outgoing = len(flights[i])
            max_key = i
```

Or in the shorter version:

```
def outgoing(flights):
    out_dict = {i: len(i) for i in flights}
    max_out = max(out_dict, key=out_dict.get)
    print(max_out)
    print(flights[max_out])
```

Comment: def outgoing(flights):
    length = 0
    for i in (flights):
        if (len(flights[i]) > length):
            length = (len(flights[i]))
            break
        else:
           continue

    for i in flights:
        if (len(flights[i]) == length):
            pop = (len(flights[i]))
            
    print ("the most outgoing flight is: " , [i])
 
I tried this and this is suppose to work, but for some reason it isn't giving me the max value from the file. Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm not sure about your indentation but does this value always give you the first flight? I don't think you want a break statement in there.

Answer (score 0):

You weren't very clear about the structure of `flights`, so I'm going to assume it's a the keys are strings and the values are lists of strings.

One way to do this would be to create a list of tuples, where each element is `(departure_city, len(flights[departure_city]))`. Then you can sort the list by number of arrivals.

```
def outgoing(flights):
    # Create a list of tuples
    flight_tups = [(departure_city, len(flights[departure_city])) for departure_city in flights]

    # Sort the list by number of arrivals
    #   We do this by passing a lambda to `sort`,
    #   telling it to sort by the second value in
    #   each tuple, i.e. arrivals
    flight_tups.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])

    # We can now get the city with the most arrivals by
    #   taking the first element of flight_tups
    most = flight_tups[0]
    print(f'City: {most[0]}\nNumber of Arrivals: {most[1]}')
```

Note: you can also use `max`, but from your question it seemed like you wanted 
the citie​**s** with the most arrivals, not just the one city with the most. Using `sort` will also let you tell if there's a tie.